# Google Map V3.0 Using Custom Marker

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

Hi I am doing a project on Integration of google map v3.0. I finished the integration I am happy with the Output. The Problem is I was trying to change the RED Marker to Custom Marker. I have saved a marker in my solution. And was trying with this piece of code.
The Program is running but i am not getting any marker on the map(either red marker  or custom marker). I tried in many blogs but couldnot find a solution.

Please anyone Help me Out.

```
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("icon55.png");
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon
               });
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I have been doing markers with customer icons:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: theMap,
            title: title,
            icon: icon
        });
```

Here latlng is a google.maps.LatLng object, theMap is the google.maps.Map object, title is a string, icon is the url to the customer marker image.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Thanks Bob...var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../Images Headers/icon55.png',
                      new google.maps.Size(40, 34),
                      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                      new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

Comment: I used this to get my output..The programming is working fine....I did not understand the usage of second point.

Comment: I researched in google documentation ImageMarker Class Size represent size of the image and One Orgin Point and one Anchor POint...I did not understand the usage of Points. If Possible can u explain me Please. Thank You

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty jsbin. I am leaching a marker, please forgive me. http://jsbin.com/ifoba3/3/edit